# discover static library dependencies

Tags: c, build, dependencies

I know that I can discover the header file dependencies required when building an object file using a few tools (such as gcc -MD ...)

Is there a similar way to determine the static libraries that will be used when a component is linked?

In particular I am looking at some multi-level make files with lots of indirection and I would like to just be able to get a list of the depedencies for that build so I can streamline my build system's rebuild requests.

ex:

```
make foo.mak
```

**foo.mak**

```
OBJS = bar.o \
 bar2.o

DEPS = core\
 msg\
 utils\

EXTRA_FLAGS +=  -Wall -Werror

include ../common/common.mak
```

within common.mak
the members of `DEPS` will be expanded in various ways depending opn what type of build this is. they may be static, shared or even kernel libraires and they may get pre- or post- fixes.

I would want to get

```
ABC_core_DEF.a
GEH_msg_IJK.a
```

(assuming that core and msg were the only dependencies to have expanded to actual static includes and that the pre and post fixes were as shown.)

Comment: The static libraries that are linked are whatever *you* specify.  In what sense do you propose to automate this?  (In other words, how is the build system supposed to figure this out *a priori*?)

Comment: example: In a top level make file I can create some lists of files and components used, then in a lower level make file common to all components in the project the various build commands actually get created, these vary based on a large number of factcors. 
so I would like to be able to inject an option to dump the actual list of static libraries used for each module rather than try to hack back thru this (very) long make script.

Comment: @tletnes: Please edit your question to include a concrete example of the sort of thing you'd like to automate.

Comment: @karlphillip I have accepted one, for the others I don't see any good answers, and I don't see the point in perpetuating bad answers.

Comment: Do you want to know which libraries are linked into a module, or which libraries the module actually needs?

Comment: Ideally I would like to know the ones actually needed, but I think that at link time we can only know what libaraies will be linked in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your build system supports a mode where the compilation commands are shown (e.g., some setting like VERBOSE=1), you could try and grep this output for items looking like -l (or whatever other kind of linker options your target toolchain uses).

Comment: This might be the only way, but I'm hoping to avoid a solution like this especially since several teams working on the project use different output hiding methods and verbose flags.